# Gap in X-Axis in Highcharts.js Line chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to implement gaps on x-axis on highchart.js line chart. The scenario is : if the x-axis has values 1,2,3,5,7,10,30, then x-axis scale should show the gap between 1 & 2 as 1-unit, between 3 & 5 as 2-units (because 5-3=2), between 7 & 10 as 3-units and between 10 & 30 as 20-units.

So, the scale should be self adjustable depending on the difference of values between current and previous values.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Vipul Jain, Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4926/ ?

Comment: Thanks ppotaczek, this solves my issue.